# Is this bid’ah ? Praying two volontary raka’ats

Tags: sharia, shaitan, bidah

I heard on a trusted Youtube channel (IloveUAllah) that to make shaytan hate to give you whispers and make you lazy for salat you can pray 2 rakats to make the shaytan less powerful.

Is it bid’ah to do it ? Is it bid’ah because there is a limited amount of (waajib and sunnah and nafl) voluntary prayers one can do in a full day ? Jazzakumu Allah.[image: here is the table of prayers I am referring to]

Comment: Who said that there are only 12 wajib, sunnah and nafl a day and which ones do you mean?

Comment: I added a picture and you can see that there is a limited amount of voluntary prayers one can do in a day. I don’t even know if one can do more than this.

Comment: And where the voluntary night prayers, two raka'as for tahiyyat al-Masjid, doha, two raka'as before Istikhara etc. fit in this table? I do assume this represents Hanafi recommendation.

Comment: Okay, so can I pray two rakats without it being neither a nafl nor a sunnah nor a farz nor a waajib ? Is it bid’ah or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Praying two raka'as nafl can never be a bid'ah because nafl (voluntary acts) have no limitation.

For example there's a known hadith (see [here](https://sunnah.com/urn/735670)) about Bilal () using to perform two raka'as nafl after each wudu'.

What could be a bid'ah is considering it a Sunnah of the prophet to pray two raka'as in order to weaken Shaytan without any proof. And what would be worse is telling others to follow this "sunnah".
It could rather be better (or sunnah) to consider doing similar to Bilal, as this was approved by our prophet ().